# Successor to ggplot2::fortify

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom

In the most recent version of `ggplot2`, `?fortify` returns:

> **Description**
>
> Rather than using this function, I now recomend using the **broom**
>   package, which implements a much wider range of methods. `fortify` may
>   be deprecated in the future.

The `broom` package indeed offers many alternatives (such as `augment`). Which one should be used in what circumstances?

I am particularly interested in an alternative to `fortify(spdf)` where `spdf` is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's how I approached the subject.

After searching "broom cran" I was redirected to the corresponding page of the package on CRAN. It offers a few vignettes so I checked out *Introduction to broom*. After failing to find any string matching "spatial" I closed the PDF and opened the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/broom.pdf). Searching for "spatial" I got 7 hits, with the first one on the topic of sp_tidiers. Function `tidy` is advertised to convert a spatial object to a data.frame. Let's try it.

```
library(sp)
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
x = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)

library(broom)

tidy(x)

   long lat order  hole piece  group   id
1     2   2     1 FALSE     1   s1.1   s1
2     1   4     2 FALSE     1   s1.1   s1
3     4   5     3 FALSE     1   s1.1   s1
4     4   3     4 FALSE     1   s1.1   s1
5     2   2     5 FALSE     1   s1.1   s1
6     5   2     1 FALSE     1   s2.1   s2
7     2   2     2 FALSE     1   s2.1   s2
8     4   3     3 FALSE     1   s2.1   s2
9     5   2     4 FALSE     1   s2.1   s2
10    4   5     1 FALSE     1 s3/4.1 s3/4
11   10   5     2 FALSE     1 s3/4.1 s3/4
12    5   2     3 FALSE     1 s3/4.1 s3/4
13    4   3     4 FALSE     1 s3/4.1 s3/4
14    4   5     5 FALSE     1 s3/4.1 s3/4
15    5   4     6  TRUE     2 s3/4.2 s3/4
16    5   3     7  TRUE     2 s3/4.2 s3/4
17    6   3     8  TRUE     2 s3/4.2 s3/4
18    6   4     9  TRUE     2 s3/4.2 s3/4
19    5   4    10  TRUE     2 s3/4.2 s3/4
```

Answer (score 14):

Posting this to solely show that the `tidy` version is near duplicate of the `fortify` version It even says as much in the `tidy` docs:

> These functions originated in the ggplot2 package as "fortify" functions.

#### `broom:::tidy.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`

```
function (x, region = NULL, ...) 
{
    attr <- as.data.frame(x)
    if (is.null(region)) {
        coords <- ldply(x@polygons, tidy)
        message("Regions defined for each Polygons")
    }
    else {
        cp <- sp::polygons(x)
        unioned <- maptools::unionSpatialPolygons(cp, attr[, 
            region])
        coords <- tidy(unioned)
        coords$order <- 1:nrow(coords)
    }
    coords
}
```

#### `ggplot2:::fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`

```
function (model, data, region = NULL, ...) 
{
    attr <- as.data.frame(model)
    if (is.null(region)) {
        coords <- plyr::ldply(model@polygons, fortify)
        message("Regions defined for each Polygons")
    }
    else {
        cp <- sp::polygons(model)
        unioned <- maptools::unionSpatialPolygons(cp, attr[, 
            region])
        coords <- fortify(unioned)
        coords$order <- 1:nrow(coords)
    }
    coords
}
```

I say *near* since the subtle differences in the `tidy` implementation (vs `fortify`) cause differences in the *order* of the generated data.frame columns. 
So, they have all of the "slowness" baggage the `fortify` version does on larger spatial objects and there's no compelling reason to switch (IMO) until `fortify` is deprecated.

Comment: is there a simple/straightforward way to improve the implementation? (I ask because `broom`, unlike `fortify`, is under active development ...)

Comment: With regard to the quote, it's worth noting that the `broom` manual says the same thing about `augment`, which is what lead to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, it is `augment()` that produces the same output as `fortify`. The difference lies in the fact that it restitues a tibble instead of a data frame.