# Map FAO fishing areas in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, geospatial

I would like to make a map in R that colours in the FAO Fishing Areas according to a data set (in my case, length data of shark species).

[image: FAO Fishing Areas]

I would prefer to do a choropleth map in `ggplot` but other types of maps are also fine.  Worst case scenario a base map of FAO areas that I can add bubbles to.  Even just an existing base map of FAO areas would be great. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I got a little farther by looking into how to upload JSON files into R, e.g. [choropleth maping](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/327-chloropleth-map-from-geojson-with-ggplot2.html),  and the data that I want is indeed in the link you suggested.  I can get JSON files into R from other sources but I haven't been able to make the FAO resources work.  What I'm still confused about is how to upload the links provided in the FAO map catalog into R as json files (or even as a dataframe would be ok).  I've tried using the packages jsonlite and geojsonio but no success.  Any more pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I went to [this page](https://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=22541) and clicked through to find [this link](http://www.fao.org/fishery/geoserver/fifao/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=fifao:FAO_AREAS_CWP&outputFormat=json) to retrieve a GeoJSON file:

```r
download.file("http://www.fao.org/fishery/geoserver/fifao/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=fifao:FAO_AREAS_CWP&outputFormat=json", dest="FAO.json")
```

From here on, I was following [this example from the R graph gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/327-chloropleth-map-from-geojson-with-ggplot2.html), with a little help from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543468/successor-to-ggplot2fortify) and [these notes](https://cfss.uchicago.edu/notes/vector-maps/):

```r
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)    ## for joining values to map

spdf <- geojson_read("FAO.json",  what = "sp")
```

At this point, `plot(spdf)` will bring up a plain (base-R) plot of the regions.

```r
spdf_fortified <- tidy(spdf)
## make up some data to go with ...
fake_fish <- data.frame(id = as.character(1:324), value = rnorm(324))
spdf2 <- spdf_fortified %>% left_join(fake_fish, by = "id")
ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = spdf2, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = group,
                                            fill = value), color="grey") +
    scale_fill_viridis_c() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'lightgray', colour = NA)) +
    coord_map() +
    coord_sf(crs = "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=45") ## Gall projection

ggsave("FAO.png")
```

[image: Gall projection]

### notes

- some of the steps are slow, it might be worth looking up how to coarsen/lower resolution of a spatial polygons object (if you just want to show the picture, the level of resolution might be overkill)
- to be honest the default sequential colour scheme might be better but all the cool kids seem to like "viridis" these days so ...
- There are probably better ways to do a lot of these pieces (e.g. set map projection, fill in background colour for land masses, ... ?)

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click on  the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: A few comments that may help speed: `sp` is now superseded by `sf`, and I believe `ggplot2` has been improved to better handle (in terms of speed) `sf` objects. So this may be an improvement you could make. And `sf` can read geojson directly, so no need for `geojsonio` (which again can be quite slow depending on the size of object).