# Plot maritime boundaries in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]Hi,

I am struggling to plot a map for EU countries with their maritime boundaries. I didn't find any R example doing something similar.

Could anyone give an example? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have access to shapefiles describing these polygons? Can you post a link? Vaguely similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472014/map-fao-fishing-areas-in-r/68536706#68536706

Comment: e.g. https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/maritime-boundaries

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your help! I have found the data from eea.europa.eu as well. I need to spend some time trying how to use and plot them.